# Three.js ShaderMaterial lighting not working

Tags: three.js, lighting, shadermaterial

I'm experimenting with Three.js ShaderMaterial and trying to implement lighting.
I have working code for r70 but the same code (with minor changes - the MAX_POINT_LIGHTS constant has been renamed NUM_POINT_LIGHTS) doesn't work for r76.

Looking at a trace in WebGL Inspector it's clear that no light data is being sent to the shader. So, has lighting broken or do I need to set up something else to get it to work?

## Using r70 (working)

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KzjXNr?editors=1010

**Fragment Shader**

```
uniform vec3 diffuse;
varying vec3 vPos;
varying vec3 vNormal;
uniform vec3 pointLightColor[MAX_POINT_LIGHTS];
uniform vec3 pointLightPosition[MAX_POINT_LIGHTS];
uniform float pointLightDistance[MAX_POINT_LIGHTS];

void main() {
  vec4 addedLights = vec4(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1.0);
  for(int l = 0; l < MAX_POINT_LIGHTS; l++) {
    vec3 lightDirection = normalize(vPos - pointLightPosition[l]);
    addedLights.rgb += clamp(dot(-lightDirection, vNormal), 0.0, 1.0) * pointLightColor[l];
  }
  gl_FragColor = addedLights;
}
```

**JavaScript - setting up the Shadermaterial with UniformsUtils and UniformsLib**

```
var uniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.merge([
    THREE.UniformsLib['lights'],
    { diffuse: { type: 'c', value: new THREE.Color(0xff00ff) } }
]);
var vertexShader = document.getElementById('vertexShader').text;
var fragmentShader = document.getElementById('fragmentShader').text;
material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
      uniforms: uniforms,
      vertexShader: vertexShader,
      fragmentShader: fragmentShader,
      lights: true
    });

var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(200, 200, 200);
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);
```

## Using r76 (futzed)

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZWdXLZ?editors=1010

**Fragment Shader**

```
uniform vec3 diffuse;
varying vec3 vPos;
varying vec3 vNormal;
uniform vec3 pointLightColor[NUM_POINT_LIGHTS];
uniform vec3 pointLightPosition[NUM_POINT_LIGHTS];
uniform float pointLightDistance[NUM_POINT_LIGHTS];

void main() {
  vec4 addedLights = vec4(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1.0);
  for(int l = 0; l < NUM_POINT_LIGHTS; l++) {
    vec3 lightDirection = normalize(vPos - pointLightPosition[l]);
    addedLights.rgb += clamp(dot(-lightDirection, vNormal), 0.0, 1.0) * pointLightColor[l];
  }
  gl_FragColor = addedLights;
}
```

**JavaScript**

Unchanged

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The light uniforms have been changed to `struct`s in [r74](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/releases/tag/r74) (Specifically in [#7324](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/7324)). Note that though the change to `struct`s happened in r74, the following works r75 and later.

A single array of `struct`s is given for each light type. Each `struct` has the `position` and `color` properties you need.

**Fragment Shader**

```
uniform vec3 diffuse;
varying vec3 vPos;
varying vec3 vNormal;

struct PointLight {
  vec3 position;
  vec3 color;
};
uniform PointLight pointLights[ NUM_POINT_LIGHTS ];

void main() {
  vec4 addedLights = vec4(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1.0);
  for(int l = 0; l < NUM_POINT_LIGHTS; l++) {
    vec3 adjustedLight = pointLights[l].position + cameraPosition;
    vec3 lightDirection = normalize(vPos - adjustedLight);
    addedLights.rgb += clamp(dot(-lightDirection, vNormal), 0.0, 1.0) * pointLights[l].color;
  }
  gl_FragColor = addedLights;//mix(vec4(diffuse.x, diffuse.y, diffuse.z, 1.0), addedLights, addedLights);
}
```

Note that the light position is now relative to the camera so you offset the light position with the camera position.

[Working Fiddle](http://codepen.io/lejeunerenard/pen/MyMLWP)

Comment: Thanks. Where did you get this info? I tried looking at the changelog but couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: I searched for a commit where `pointLightColor` was changed and then figured out what release it would have been included in. Then I looked for where the attributes are used in the repo and found the [`lights_pars.glsl` ShaderChunk](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/lights_pars.glsl). So lots of searching. :)

Comment: And since cameraPosition is a uniform isn't it already available to both shaders, and hence no varying needed?

Comment: Wow, that is a **lot** of searching! Not exactly intuitive or self-evident.

Comment: Huh. You're right about `cameraPosition`! I thought I had tried that but apparently not. I'll update the answer to remove the `varying`. It was a **lot** of searching.